# Add and align titles with background to arranged ggplots

Tags: r, ggplot2

stack!
I have some ggplots that I'd like to arrange in one plot with titles in a facet-like fashion. Sadly, due to the complexity of the data and variety of plots, I don't think I can make one data table and produce a faceted plot. So far, with the following code, I've managed to get the result shown here.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
library(grid)

plot.data<- data.frame("v1"=rnorm(20), "v2"=rnorm(20))

plot1<- ggplot(data= plot.data) + geom_point(aes(x=v1, y=v2))
plot2<- plot1
plot3<- plot1 + coord_polar()
plot4<- plot1 + coord_polar()

blank<- rectGrob(gp=gpar(fill="white", col="white"))

title1 <- grobTree(rectGrob(gp=gpar(fill="#EAECEE", col="white", lwd=5)),
                 textGrob("title 1", gp=gpar(col="black", fontsize= 20)))

title2 <- grobTree(rectGrob(gp=gpar(fill="#EAECEE", col="white", lwd=5)),
                   textGrob("title 2", gp=gpar(col="black", fontsize= 20)))

title3 <- grobTree(rectGrob(gp=gpar(fill="#EAECEE", col="white", lwd=5)),
                   textGrob("title 3", rot = 90, gp=gpar(col="black", fontsize= 20)))

title4 <- grobTree(rectGrob(gp=gpar(fill="#EAECEE", col="white", lwd=5)),
                   textGrob("title 4", rot = 90, gp=gpar(col="black", fontsize= 20)))

ggarrange(ggarrange(blank, title1, title2, ncol=3, widths = c(1, 5, 5)),
          ggarrange(title3, plot1, plot2, title4, plot3, plot4, ncol=3, nrow=2, widths = c(1, 5, 5)),
          nrow=2, heights= c(1, 10))
```

[image: multiple plot]

But I am not quite satisfied with the result because I'd like the title bars to be aligned with the plot areas (currently they are as wide as the plots with axis labels). I wonder if there is a way to better align the titles with the plots (so as to get a nicer look), without resorting to white boxes and lines.
Any advice on how to improve the looks of a multiple-plot like this is welcomed as well.

Comment: One solution is to `fill = "white"` instead of `fill = "#EAECEE` and just ignore the problem :-)